# Probability of $0.55$ for a fair coin

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Imagine we have a fair coin that comes with probability of $0.5$ for  head. Is it possible that this coin makes a probability of $0.55$? What about $\frac{1}{3}$ ?

Comment: I do not understand your question... Are you asking whether there exists some way of using a perfectly fair coin to simulate an experiment that has a theoretical probability of $0.55$ or of $1/3$?  No.  All events in any experiment involving flipping a fair coin repeatedly will always have probability which can be expressed as $0$ or as $\frac{2k+1}{2^n}$ for some integers $k$ and $n$.  $0.55$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ can not be written in such a form.

Comment: Can you explain how was this formula (2k+1)/2^n obtain?

Comment: Hint: consider what you could do with multiple coin flips and keeping an option to ignore certain results and try again.

Comment: I should clarify, it is impossible if you want an upper bound on number of flips.  Because flipping $N$ coins in sequence and treating the order of the flips as relevant, we have a sample space size of $2^N$ of equally likely outcomes, the probability of an event in such a sample space would be $\frac{|E|}{2^N}$ which when written in simplest terms results in an odd (*or zero*) numerator and a denominator a power of $2$.  If you allow for "*try agains*" like Brian suggests, then you could potentially have to flip billions and billions of times (*with nonzero probability*)

Comment: Are you asking (for example) if you happen to flip a coin 60 times, what is the chances of getting exactly 33 heads, or exactly 20 heads?  Note, that if you are asking such a question, then **even assuming** a fair coin, the chances of exactly 30 heads out of 60 coin tosses (for example) is *very small*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the probability $p$ you want to simulate as a binary decimal, e.g. $0.55=0.100011\ldots$ (from $0.55={1\over2}+{1\over32}+{1\over64}+\cdots$) or ${1\over3}=0.010101\ldots$. Then toss your fair coin repeatedly, recording the string of Heads and Tails as a binary decimal, with Heads as $1$ and Tails as $0$. Continue doing so until the string departs from the binary decimal for $p$. If the departure is *less* than $p$, consider it a win, if more than $p$, a loss.

Interestingly, the average number of tosses required is always $2$, regardless of the value for $p$.

This algorithm, which I by no means invented (I do not remember where I first came across it), takes some getting used to. For one thing, the simulation terminates half the time after a single toss of the fair coin, which seems counterintuitive. One way to understand why it works is to imagine you have a friend who continues to toss the fair coin *ad infinitum*, adding to the string of Heads and Tails, thereby creating a random number between $0$ and $1$.  With probability $p$ this random number is in the interval $(0,p)$ and with probability $1-p$ it's in the interval $(p,1)$ (and with probability $0$ it's exactly equal to $p$.) The point is, you don't need to pay any attention to your friend's tosses, because the interval the number lands is was determined with the final toss you made.

Comment: I remember seeing this kind of stuff in the old post about simulating a N-sided dice with normal 6-sided dices (the link should be somewhere in here).